# Does Sorbet add signatures for standard lib?

Tags: ruby, sorbet

I would want Sorbet to raise a warning when code like this is written:

```
list = list.sort!
```

As I would expect `Array#sort!` to be of type `void`

Comment: I think you should probably ask in [sorbet repo](https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet) issue

Comment: @MartinZinovsky The sorbet team explicitly requested questions go on SO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Sorbet does include types for standard library of Ruby.
For example, here's the type annotation for `sort!`
https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/blob/119e937e9e3b03ec27308cd8874f482791d15864/rbi/core/array.rbi#L670-L677

Note that in Ruby `sort!` does return a value and Sorbet correctly models that.

Comment: I see thank you, I would just expect that as sort! is a mutation method it should not return a value